# pygtk how to update gtk.Image

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

I have very strange problem with gtk.Image(). Simple question; how to update image?
On window creation I create image and pack it… On that time I load image from disk. Now I start downloading image from url, and when it's done I just want to replace existing image with new one. I rewrite content of same file on disk and then do:

```
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image_path)
    self._user_avatar.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

I have tried
        self._user_avatar.set_from_file(image_path) 
and
        self._user_avatar.clear()
nothing works. When i restart app there is a new image and everything is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gtk.Image.set_from_pixbuf`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkimage.html#method-gtkimage--set-from-pixbuf) is the right method, so your problem may come from something else. Try on the most simple piece of code to reproduce your problem.

Here's a working sample:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

pics = []
clicks = 0

def on_destroy (widget):
    gtk.main_quit()
    return False

def on_button_clicked (widget, image):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    image.set_from_pixbuf (pics[clicks % len(pics)])

def create ():
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.connect("destroy", on_destroy)

    pics.append (gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("sample1.png"))
    pics.append (gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("sample2.png"))

    image = gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_pixbuf(pics[0])

    button = gtk.Button ("Switch Image")
    button.connect("clicked", on_button_clicked, image)

    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    vbox.pack_start (image)
    vbox.pack_start (button)

    window.add(vbox)
    window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Your example works fine, so there is something in my code that making problem. Anyway thanks man.