# Python GTK update an image in a Fixed container (noob at GTK)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have tried a lot and I keep failing. This will be very easy for someone with GUI experience. Please give some examples or a restruction of my code.

I am trying to create something similar to Conky (not an option for now). A full-screen window to display informations like text and images on the desktop. I need help with the skeleton of the gtk script. I want the ability to display multiple images (at custom position) from the disk, that update every 10 minutes and also text from files or commands.

for now I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import gtk
import sys
import cairo



def transparent_expose(widget, event):
    """ Make the given widget transparent. """
    cr = widget.window.cairo_create()
    cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_CLEAR)
    region = gtk.gdk.region_rectangle(event.area)
    cr.region(region)
    cr.fill()
    return False


class PyApp(gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    super(PyApp, self).__init__()

    self.set_title("Fixed")
    self.set_size_request(1300, 280)
    self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(6400, 6400, 6440))
    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

    screen = self.get_screen()
    rgba = screen.get_rgba_colormap()
    self.set_colormap(rgba)
    self.set_app_paintable(True)
    self.connect("expose-event", transparent_expose)


def wetherchart(self):
    try:
        self.thessaloniki = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/dev/shm/WEATHER/Thessaloniki.comb.png")
    except Exception, e:
        self.thessaloniki = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/home/athan/LOGs/wait.svg")

    try:
        self.katerini = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/dev/shm/WEATHER/Katerini.comb.png")
    except Exception, e:
        self.katerini = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/home/athan/LOGs/wait.svg")

    try:
        self.florina = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/dev/shm/WEATHER/Florina.comb.png")
    except Exception, e:
        self.florina = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/home/athan/LOGs/wait.svg")


    self.thessaloniki = self.thessaloniki.scale_simple(505,240,gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
    self.katerini = self.katerini.scale_simple(505,240,gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
    self.florina = self.florina.scale_simple(505,240,gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)

    image1 = gtk.Image()
    image2 = gtk.Image()
    image3 = gtk.Image()

    image1.set_from_pixbuf(self.thessaloniki)
    image2.set_from_pixbuf(self.katerini)
    image3.set_from_pixbuf(self.florina)

    fix = gtk.Fixed()

    fix.put(image1, 515, 3)
    fix.put(image2, 1025, 3)
    fix.put(image3, 5, 3)

    self.add(fix)

    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    self.show_all()

PyApp()
#gtk.main()


def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyApp()
    app.wetherchart()


    #~ 
    #~ backups=Backups()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( 15* 1000, backups.update)
#~ 
    #~ calendar=Calendar()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( 1 * 1000, calendar.update)
#~ 
    #~ disks=Disks()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( 5 * 60 * 1000 , disks.update)
#~ 
    #~ events=Events()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( 10 * 1000 , events.update)
#~ 
    #~ process = Process()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( int(0.5 * 1000), process.update)
#~ 
    #~ running = Running()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( 60 * 1000, running.update)
#~ 
    #~ temps = Temps()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( int(2 * 1000), temps.update)
#~ 
    #~ transmision = Transmision()
    #~ gtk.timeout_add( int(1 * 1000), transmision.update)

    main()
```

it runs ok, but i didn't manage to make it refresh the images.
I will appreciate a general solution for placing and refreshing multiple images and text labels.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819952/how-to-display-continuous-data-in-a-py-gtk-window

Comment: i had tried this, i didn't manage to make it work for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938949/pygtk-how-to-update-gtk-image its work ! i tested. hope helpful

Comment: By "refresh the images" do you mean "change the images"? If so, you will probably want to use GtkDrawingArea or even Clutter to do this instead of GtkFixed and GtkImage...

Comment: I mean just reload from disk, no editing. I am struggling a lot of time but object oriented coding and GTK confuses too much to figure this out. If anyone could give me a simple template...  I need to be able to load images and labels on my desktop and refresh them in custom intervals. Is not going to be an actual application.

Comment: The images are recreated constantly by other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was failing because i omit `return True` from the update function!!!

Here is a working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pygtk
import gtk
from datetime import datetime

class Base:

    def one(self):
        try:
            katerini = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/dev/shm/WEATHER/Katerini.comb.png")
        except Exception, e:
            katerini = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/home/athan/LOGs/wait.svg")
        katerini = katerini.scale_simple(505,240,gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)

        self.image.set_from_pixbuf( katerini )
        self.label.set_text(str(datetime.now()))
        print "load"
        print datetime.now()
        return True

    def tik(self):
        self.label.set_text(str(datetime.now()))
        return True


    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        #~ #self.window.fullscreen()
        self.window.set_size_request(1300, 280)

        self.image = gtk.Image()
        self.label = gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text(str(datetime.now()))

        fix = gtk.Fixed()
        gtk.timeout_add( 1000, self.one)

        fix.put(self.image, 5, 3)
        fix.put(self.label, 520, 3)

        #self.window.add(self.image)
        self.window.add(fix)
        self.image.show()
        self.window.show_all()


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "main"
    Base().main()
    gtk.timeout_add(10, Base.one )
```

Thanks for the help!